# MySQL Count Where Two Columns are Same and Not Null, Same Table

Tags: mysql, sql, join, count, null

I have a table with the following data:

```
mysql> describe Post;
+-------------+--------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
| Field       | Type         | Null | Key | Default | Extra          |
+-------------+--------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
| id          | int(11)      | NO   | PRI | NULL    | auto_increment |
| user_id     | int(11)      | NO   | MUL | NULL    |                |
| post_date   | datetime     | NO   |     | NULL    |                |
| in_reply_to | int(11)      | YES  |     | NULL    |                |
| text        | varchar(160) | NO   |     | NULL    |                |
+-------------+--------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+

mysql> select id as "Row ID", user_id as "User ID", post_date as "Post Date", IF(in_reply_to is NULL, "None", in_reply_to) as "In Reply To Post ID:", CONCAT(LEFT(text,40),"...") as "Post Text" from Post;
+--------+---------+---------------------+----------------------+---------------------------------------------+
| Row ID | User ID | Post Date           | In Reply To Post ID: | Post Text                                   |
+--------+---------+---------------------+----------------------+---------------------------------------------+
|      1 |       1 | 2015-08-14 20:38:00 | None                 | This is the original test post that I pu... |
|      2 |       2 | 2015-08-14 20:39:00 | None                 | This is the second post that I put into ... |
|      3 |       5 | 2015-08-14 22:00:00 | 1                    | Hahaha, that post was hilarious. I canno... |
|      4 |       4 | 2015-08-14 23:00:00 | 1                    | Today I saw a cat jump off the roof, ont... |
|      5 |       4 | 2015-08-14 23:00:00 | None                 | Today I saw a cat jump off the roof, ont... |
|     27 |       1 | 2015-09-08 05:53:40 | 2                    | This is a mad reply ay...                   |
|     28 |       1 | 2015-09-08 11:24:05 | None                 | Yolo Swag...                                |
+--------+---------+---------------------+----------------------+---------------------------------------------+
7 rows in set (0.05 sec)
```

Each of the columns have a description if you are not sure of what they represent. The two columns I am concerned with for this question are `id` and `in_reply_to`.

`in_reply_to` is a `NULLABLE` FK integer that references `id` in the same table; if `in_reply_to` is `NULL`, it means the post is an original post, if it is an integer value, it is a reply post and represents the id of the post that it is a reply to.

In the below example there are 4 original posts (1, 2, 5, 28) and 3 replies (3, 4, 27), ie 3 is a reply to 1, 4 is also a reply to 1, and 27 is a reply to 2. I'm looking to perform an SQL query that produces output like below:

[image: intended output]

Where `Num Replies` is a `COUNT` of how rows there are in the same table that have their `in_reply_to` equal to `id`; displaying `0` if there are no replies to that post (ie no rows contain the id for the particular post as their `in_reply_to` column.

Thanks.

**Solution (as per Anders' answer):**

```
mysql> SELECT   Post.id, Post.user_id, Post.post_date, Post.in_reply_to, CONCAT(LEFT(Post.text,40)),   IF(counts.count IS NULL, 0, counts.count) AS 'Num of Replies' FROM Post LEFT JOIN    (SELECT      in_reply_to AS id,      COUNT(*) AS count    FROM Post    WHERE in_reply_to IS NOT NULL    GROUP BY in_reply_to) AS counts  ON Post.id = counts.id;
+----+---------+---------------------+-------------+------------------------------------------+----------------+
| id | user_id | post_date           | in_reply_to | CONCAT(LEFT(Post.text,40))               | Num of Replies |
+----+---------+---------------------+-------------+------------------------------------------+----------------+
|  1 |       1 | 2015-08-14 20:38:00 |        NULL | This is the original test post that I pu |              2 |
|  2 |       2 | 2015-08-14 20:39:00 |        NULL | This is the second post that I put into  |              1 |
|  3 |       5 | 2015-08-14 22:00:00 |           1 | Hahaha, that post was hilarious. I canno |              0 |
|  4 |       4 | 2015-08-14 23:00:00 |           1 | Today I saw a cat jump off the roof, ont |              0 |
|  5 |       4 | 2015-08-14 23:00:00 |        NULL | Today I saw a cat jump off the roof, ont |              0 |
| 27 |       1 | 2015-09-08 05:53:40 |           2 | This is a mad reply ay                   |              0 |
| 28 |       1 | 2015-09-08 11:24:05 |        NULL | Random Text                              |              0 |
+----+---------+---------------------+-------------+------------------------------------------+----------------+
7 rows in set (0.00 sec)
```

Comment: Your first image is broken. Please include all data as text instead of images.

Comment: @Anders I have replaced it now.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to join two queries on the same table. The first one just selects all the posts, the second one counts the number of replies for each post. It's a left join since you want to include the posts without any replies (that will not  be returned from the second query). The `IF` is there to convert `NULL` values to `0` for those.

```
SELECT
  post.id,
  -- Other fields...,
  IF(counts.count IS NULL, 0, counts.count) AS count
FROM post
LEFT JOIN 
  (SELECT
     in_reply_to AS id,
     COUNT(*) AS count
   FROM post
   WHERE in_reply_to IS NOT NULL
   GROUP BY in_reply_to) AS counts
 ON post.id = counts.id
```

*Disclaimar: I have not tested this.*

Answer (score 0):

You can do a join in the traditional way, or you can do the join straight in the new column.

Example:

```
select a.id, 
(select count(*) from (select 1 as id union all select 1 union all select 2)b where b.id=a.id) as count_of_replies

 from 
    (select 1 as id union all select 1  union all select 2)a
```

note the 2 subquery 'tables' are both the same table.